# How to run a C program in bash script and give it some values of a defined constant?

Tags: c, bash

I have a program in C (`bact.c`), where I define a constant value N.

I would then like to run the code for different values of N,
not consecutively (e.g. N=100,120,300,350,426...).

How can I automate the process with a script, which loops over the 
chosen values N? Is it possible without `scanf`?

Comment: *I would then like to run the code* - this is hardly a *code*. And there is nothing to *run*.

Comment: I do not think it is necessary to write the entire code, being very long and completely ininfluent to the question

Comment: Show us what you tried and explain what specifically is confusing about why it doesn't work. We don't just write your code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would only work if your program accepts the value of `N` as a command-line argument.

If you call your program as `./a.out 3` where `3` is the value for `N`, then you could write a one-liner in the terminal as:

`for N in {100,120,300,350,426}; do ./a.out $N; done`

You can even make a script out of it if you like.

Comment: Why not: `for N in 100 120 300 350 426; do ./a.out $n; done`?  There's no need for the curly-brace notation.

Comment: Mentioned the braces just for clarity.